# How to get current price from while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hello guy's and girls,

As you can see below I have the Jquery code and PHP/HTML code. You can see the price variable inside the Jquery code. The console log prints all the prices of all the products but I want the current price value from the current quantity click `.update-quantity` value.

`.closest` works with the quantity form. I tried to do the same with the price-form but I can't figure it out.

Sorry for this I am a beginner on understanding taking values from the while loop with jQuery

**//Jquery function**

```
$(".update-quantity").click(function(e){
  var id       = $(this).data('id');
  var quantity = $(this).closest('.update-quantity-form').find('.cart-quantity').text();
  var price    = $('.update-price-price-form').find('.cart-price-price').text();
  console.log("Price: "+price);
});
```

**//PHP HTML code**

```
  extract($row);

  // update quantity WORKS
  echo "<div class='update-quantity-form'>";
  <a class='update-quantity' data-id='{$id}'>-</a>
  <div class='cart-quantity'>{$quantity}</div>
  <a class='update-quantity' data-id='{$id}'>+</a>
  </div>";

  // update price DOESNT work
  echo "<div class='update-price-price-form'>";
  echo "&#8364;<span class='cart-price-price'>$price</span>";
  echo "</div>";
}
```

My goal is to use the price value and then calculate it with AJAX php file which has the quantity value. Then I will have a price and a subtotal displayed without page refresh.

Thanks for your time, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the sibling of `.update-quantity-form` and get text from there:

```
$(".update-quantity").click(function(e){
  var qf       = $(this).closest('.update-quantity-form');

  var id       = $(this).data('id');
  var quantity = qf.find('.cart-quantity').text();
  var price    = qf.siblings('.update-price-price-form').find('.cart-price-price').text();
  console.log("Price: " + price);
});
```

Comment: It was hard to find this online when i was searching. Thanks for your time and answer. I am happy now :P. Have a nice day/evening.

Comment: @Gester Glad to help :)